# How to change the status of the column in the model in django

Tags: python, django

I am creating an assignment management system, What a I want is whenever someone upload a submission in response to that assignment I want to change the status from pending, I will set everything on template page, but right now i feel like i have little issue with database.

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
    assignment_creator = models.ForeignKey(
        Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="assignments")
    assignment_title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Submissions(models.Model):
    submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    submission_file = models.FileField(null=False, blank=True, default='')
    submitted_to = models.ForeignKey(
        Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    submission_title = models.ForeignKey(
        Assignment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    submission_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Is there any way to know which of the assignment related to that assignment title is uploaded so that I can change the status

Comment: Do you want to update the value of `submission_status` each time a `Submissions` object is created ?

Comment: yes, this is what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don' t understand your design, because when a submission is created it should already be linked with the assignment (because a student makes a submission in response of an assignment). But if you really want to set `submission_title` later you could override the `save` method:

```py
class Assignment(models.Model):
    assignment_creator = models.ForeignKey(
        Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="assignments")
    assignment_title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Submissions(models.Model):
    submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    submission_file = models.FileField(null=False, blank=True, default='')
    submitted_to = models.ForeignKey(
        Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    submission_title = models.ForeignKey(
        Assignment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    submission_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.submission_title != None and not submission_status:
           self.submission_status = True
        super.save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: thanks alot, one more question my compiler isn't getting the Assignment(inside submission_title) when I write submission class above , and when I put Assignment class above it gives not defined error for submissions. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @FNasir Please provide more details about the error.