# Clicking the button in the html template does not change the "status" field in the django model

Tags: python, django, button

everyone! I have
models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    status = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='Activated')
    ...
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'posts'

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('<int:pk>/update/', views.PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='update_status')]
```

views.py

```
class PostUpdateView(UpdateView):
model = Post
template_name = 'post_detail.html'

def change_status(self):
    if request.method == "POST": 
        post = Post.objects.filter(id=self.id)
        if post.status == 'Activated':
            post.status = 'Deactivated'
            post.save()
        elif post.status == 'Deactivated':
            post.status = 'Activated'
            post.save()
    return redirect('posts:post_detail')
```

posts_detail.html

```
...
<form action="{% url 'posts:update_status' post.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="button">
    {% if post.status == 'Activated' %}
    Deactivate
    {% else %}
    Activate
    {% endif %}</button>
</form>
...
```

I want to switch the field on the button "Activate/Deactivate" and redirect to the same page. At the moment there is a button and when clicked nothing changes. Well or maybe the redirect works, but the status does not switch. I'm assuming wrong views.py, but can't figure out where.

I tried it like this

```
@require_http_methods(['POST'])
def update_status(request, id):
    if post.status == 'Activated':
        Post.objects.filter(id=id).update(status='Deactivated')
    elif post.status == 'Deactivated':
        Post.objects.filter(id=id).update(status='Activated')
    return redirect('posts:post_detail')
```

But that doesn't work either.
I know these are similar ways, but I don't have any more ideas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the status of the column in the model in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69926628/how-to-change-the-status-of-the-column-in-the-model-in-django)

Comment: @RobertBradley No, I need to switch by clicking on the button

Comment: @ ilnarkz, Got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Well or maybe the redirect works, but the status does not switch.

Does your button submits properly? Maybe **button type='submit'** is what you need. You can check does button work properly like this.

posts_detail.html

```html
...
{{alert}}
<form action="{% url 'posts:update_status' post.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if post.status == 'Activated' %}
        <button type="submit">Deactivate</button>
    {% else %}
        <button type="submit">Activate</button>
    {% endif %}
</form>
...
```

views.py

```py
def update_status(request, id):
    # For checking submit button works properly
    if self.request.method == "POST":
        context = {'alert':'POST submitted'}
        return render(request, 'templates/posts_detail.html', context)

    context = {'alert':'ready for POST'}
    return render(request, 'templates/posts_detail.html', context)
    ...
```

If it works, you can consider adding extra values to button like this for further use.

posts_detail.html

```html
...
<form action="{% url 'posts:update_status' post.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if post.status == 'Activated' %}
        <button type="submit" name="status" value="Deactivated">Deactivate</button>
    {% else %}
        <button type="submit" name="status" value="Activated">Activate</button>
    {% endif %}
</form>
...
```

views.py

```py
def update_status(request, id):
    if self.request.method == "POST":
        Post.objects.filter(id=id).update(status=request.POST['status'])
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! ```button type='submit'``` That helped a little bit. But UpdateView required to add form_class and template_name. And now it opens the page with the form to update. But I need the status to be updated when the button is clicked. Maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: I think you want to ① use class view instead of function view, ② use Button instead of CharField, right? I suggest that make your own customized form. Form field's type doesn't need to same as a model field. Plus, each form fields can be shown or hidden. That means a whole form can be embedded in template like this {{ form }} or form's each field can be embedded in template like this {{ form.name }} {{ form.slug }}. Also button that is not defnined in form can be embedded in template with form's field like this {{form.name}} <button type='submit'> {{ form.slug }} {{form.etc}}. Hope this helps

Comment: I think using function based view is good to your case. If you use FBV, you don't need to make custom form(because you need just one button), and FBV also can render pages with template using render().
If you want to use class based view, try to use formview instead of updateview.